# Airflow with mysql_to_gcp negsignal.sigkill

Tags: google-cloud-composer, airflow

I'm using airflow with composer (GCP) to extract data from cloud sql for gcs and after gcs for bigquery, I have some tables between 100 Mb and 10 Gb. My dag has two tasks to do what I mentioned before. with the smaller tables the dag runs smoothly, but with slightly larger tables the cloud sql extraction task ends in a few seconds with failure, but does not bring any logs except "negsignal.sigkill", I have already tried to increase the composer capacity , among other things, but nothing has worked yet.
I'm using the mysql_to_gcs and gcs_to_bigquery operators

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should check when you get `negsinal.SIGKILL` is your Kubernetes resources. This is surely a problem with resources limits.

I think you should monitor your Kubernetes Cluster Nodes. Inside GCP, go to Kubernetes Engine > Clusters. You should have a cluster containing the environment that Cloud Composer uses.

Now, head to the nodes of your cluster. Each node provides you metrics about CPU, memory & disk usage. You will also see the limit for the resources that each node uses. Also, you will see the pods that each node has.

If you are not very familiar with K8s, let me explain this briefly. Airflow uses Pods inside nodes to run your Airflow tasks. These pods are called **airflow-worker-[id]**. That way you can identify your worker pods inside the Node.

Check your pods list. If you have **evicted** airflow-worker pods, then Kubernetes is stopping your workers for some reason. Since Composer uses CeleryExecutor, a evicted airflow-worker points to a problem. This is not the case if you use KubernetesExecutor, but that is not available yet in Composer.

If you click in some evicted pod, you will see the reason for eviction. That should give you the answer.

If you don't see a problem with your pod eviction, don't panic, you still have some options. From that point on, your best friend will be logs. Be sure to check your pods logs, node logs and cluster logs, in that order.

Comment: Note that the resource you need to change is your machine-type if you find a problem with the Nodes resources.